# Virtual host or something else?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I want set up the following structure: 
staging.mydomain.com/client/projectname 
production.mydomain.com/client/projectname

For new projects i create the following folders in my /home/-folder:

- "clientname"-folder

  - "projectname"-folder

    - staging-folder
    - production-folder

I have made a file that I enabled with "a2ensite" including the stuff showing below.

It is working fine with clientA for "production" and "staging", but of course clientB wont work, since its something like overridden by clientA, right?

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName www.mydomain.com 
    ServerAlias mydomain.com 
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
    DocumentRoot /home/mysite 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName production.mydomain.com 
    ServerAlias production.mydomain.com 
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
    DocumentRoot /home/clientA/projectA/production 
    Alias /clientA/projectA /home/clientA/projectA/production 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName staging.mydomain.com 
    ServerAlias staging.mydomain.com 
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
    DocumentRoot /home/clientA/projectA/staging 
    Alias /clientA/projectA /home/clientA/projectA/staging 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName production.mydomain.com 
    ServerAlias production.mydomain.com 
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
    DocumentRoot /home/clientB/projectA/production 
    Alias /clientB/projectA /home/clientB/projectA/production 
</VirtualHost> 

<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName staging.mydomain.com 
    ServerAlias staging.mydomain.com 
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
    DocumentRoot /home/clientB/projectA/staging 
    Alias /clientB/projectA /home/clientB/projectA/staging 
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is working fine with clientA for "production" and "staging", but of course clientB wont work, since its something like overridden by clientA, right?

Well, you have 2 vhosts defined for the same servername:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName staging.mydomain.com 
    ServerAlias staging.mydomain.com 
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
    DocumentRoot /home/clientA/projectA/staging 
    Alias /clientA/projectA /home/clientA/projectA/staging 
</VirtualHost>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName staging.mydomain.com 
    ServerAlias staging.mydomain.com 
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php 
    DocumentRoot /home/clientB/projectA/staging 
    Alias /clientB/projectA /home/clientB/projectA/staging 
</VirtualHost>
```

The second one is going to get ignored because you've already got a vhost for the server "staging.mydomain.com", and likewise for "production.mydomain.com"

When you define these vhosts, and define them such that the `ServerName` it hosts is called "staging.mydomain.com"

When you type `http://staging.mydomain.com/`, which vhost do you expect it to go to? There are 2 of them that claim to host that hostname. You have to give these vhost different names.

Comment: Yes I see that problem. But if we just put for example one vhost for staging and one for production, how can I use that so it works with my structure: http://staging.mydomain.com/clientA/projectA points to /clientA/projectA/staging, and http://staging.mydomain.com/clientB/projectA points to /clientB/projectA and so on....?

Comment: Is there no one that have a clue about this?

Comment: @user1618992 you make it so the document root is `/home`